# How to delete all nodes with a particular data of linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I have the next problem. I have the function to delete a node of a linked list with a value int, but I need to delete all the nothes in the list with this value, how I can do it?, here is the function to delete one node with the value

```
    nodoLista* borrarMesLista(nodoLista* lista, int mes){
    nodoLista* seg;
    nodoLista* ante;
    if(lista != NULL && mes == lista->dato.mes){
        nodoLista* aux = lista;
        lista = lista->sig;
        free(aux);
    }else{
        seg=lista;
        while(seg != NULL && mes != seg->dato.mes){
            ante=seg;
            seg= seg->sig;
        }

        if(seg != NULL){
            ante->sig = seg->sig;
            free(seg);
        }
    }
    return lista;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution:

```
nodoLista* borrarTodosMesesLista(nodoLista* lista, int mes){
nodoLista* aux;
nodoLista* seg;
nodoLista* ante;

if(lista){
    while(lista != NULL && lista->dato.mes == mes){
        aux=lista;
        lista=lista->sig;
        free(aux);
    }
    seg=lista->sig;
    ante=lista;
    while(seg != NULL){
        if(seg->dato.mes == mes){
            aux=seg;
            ante->sig=seg->sig;
            seg=seg->sig;
            free(aux);
        }else{
            ante=seg;
            seg=seg->sig;
        }
    }
}
return lista;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

***This is not a very efficient method, there are other good ways to do the same.***

*but using below you will have minimal changes to your code*

To remove all entries of the same element you can modify your `borrarMesLista` function a bit by adding an extra parameter `removed`, that can be used for finding out whether an element is removed or not.

The initial value of `removed` will be `0`, in case if an element is removed then make `removed = 1`.

```
nodoLista* borrarMesLista(nodoLista* lista, int mes, int *removed){
    nodoLista* seg;
    nodoLista* ante;
    if(lista != NULL && mes == lista->dato.mes){
        nodoLista* aux = lista;
        lista = lista->sig;
        free(aux);
        *removed = 1;
    }else{
        seg=lista;
        while(seg != NULL && mes != seg->dato.mes){
            ante=seg;
            seg= seg->sig;
        }

        if(seg != NULL){
            ante->sig = seg->sig;
            free(seg);
           *removed = 1;
        }
    }
    return lista;
}
```

Also when you are calling `borrarMesLista` you need to have some control code on how long this process has to continue.This process will continue as long as there is a duplicate element present in the list.

```
int removed = 0;
while( 1 )
{
    if(removed)
        removed = 0;
    lista = borrarMesLista(lista, mes, &removed);
    if(!removed)
        break;
}
```